# How to get value from select field in controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a problem with get value from :days new form.

new.html.haml

```
= f.select :days, [['1 month', 30], ['2 months', 60], ['3 months', 90]]
```

controller

```
def create
  @bought_detail = BoughtDetail.new(bought_detail_params)
  @bought_detail.entry_type = @entry_type
  @bought_detail.person = current_person
  if @bought_detail.entry_type.kind == 'Karnet'
    @bought_detail.cost = @bought_detail.entry_type.price * (days / 30).floor
  else
    @bought_detail.cost = @bought_detail.entry_type.price
  end
end

private

def bought_detail_params
  params.require(:bought_detail).permit(:bought_data, :start_on, :end_on, :entry_type_id, :days, :person_id, :credit_card, :card_code)
end
```

Model

```
belongs_to :entry_type
belongs_to :person
before_save :set_bought_data, :set_end_on, :set_start_on

attr_accessor :credit_card, :card_code, :days

def set_bought_data
  self.bought_data = Date.today
end

def set_start_on
  self.start_on = bought_data if start_on.nil?
end

def set_end_on
  days = "7" if days.nil?
  self.end_on = Date.today + days.to_i
end
```

When I fill new form and click submit I get this error:

```
undefined local variable or method `days'
```

I want to deliver value from select field e.g. when I choose 2 months, value of the day will be `60` and I will can get calculate `@bought_detail.cost`. How to do this?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In controller you're trying to access undefined variable `days`, change to accessing the model:

```
 @bought_detail.cost = @bought_detail.entry_type.price * (@bought_detail.days.last / 30).floor
```

In model change to:

```
 self.days = "7" if days.nil?
```

because otherwise you'll be assigning to local variable, not the attribute.

Comment: @ŁukaszKorol note the changes in code, excerpts are already fixed

Answer (score 0):

In your controller's `create` method. Where are you getting the `days` from?

```
@bought_detail.cost = @bought_detail.entry_type.price * (days.last / 30).floor
```

This bit specifically: `days.last / 30`. Ruby can't find `days` method or local variable. I guess you want to access it from `params[:your_model][:days]`?